# An error occurred during the push operation: Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

amplify publish
√ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.

```
Current Environment: dev
```

┌──────────┬──────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name        │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼──────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Edge     │ LambdaEdgeProtection │ Create    │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼──────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Hosting  │ S3AndCloudFront      │ Update    │ awscloudformation │
└──────────┴──────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
? Are you sure you want to continue? Yes

Deployment failed.
Deploying root stack gltftutorial [ =============--------------------------- ] 1/3
hostingS3AndCloudFront         AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_FAILED                  Wed Oct 12 2022
amplify-gltftutorial-dev-1543… AWS::CloudFormation::Stack     UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE       Wed Oct 12 2022
Deploying edge LambdaEdgeProtection [ ---------------------------------------- ] 0/1
Deployed hosting S3AndCloudFront [ ======================================== ] 4/4

The following resources failed to deploy:
 An error occurred during the push operation:
Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete
⚠️ Review the Amplify CLI troubleshooting guide for potential next steps: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/project/troubleshooting/

Comment: Did you try deleting the stack and re-creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that a previous deploy failed and the CloudFormation stack is currently stuck. In order to fix it, you can rollback the update by going into CloudFormation in the AWS console and then try publishing again. More details about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stack-failure-options.html